# PHP date time format for UK

Tags: php, datetime

I have date variable i need to convert to a another type of date formats

```
//the date and time
$date="16-03-2014 00:16:01";
```

the format i want convert is like below

```
Sunday 16th of March 00:16:01
```

can someone please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this, also set default timezone of UK

```
<?php
   $tm = strtotime("16-03-2014 00:16:01");
   echo "<br>".date("l jS \of F H:i:s",$tm);   
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)** to create a Datetime object, then output with specified format.

```
$date="16-03-2014 00:16:01";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $date);
echo $date->format('l jS \of F H:i:s');
```

Comment: @OP ... If you are fimiliar with OOP, this is indeed the right way to go!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $date="16-03-2014 00:16:01";
    $uk_date = explode("-", str_replace(" ", "-", $date));
    $uk_date_stamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $uk_date[1], $uk_date[0], $uk_date[2]);
    $uk_date = date("l jS \of F Y", $uk_date_stamp)." ".$uk_date[3];

 echo $uk_date;

?>
```

Comment: I didn't include hours/minutes/seconds in mktime() because apparently that wasn't necessary since the output you want can be achieved this way.